# How to pass some data in chunks inside html table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have html like

```
<table id="library_info_tbl">
  <thead>
    <th>Call No.</th>
    <th>Book</th>
    <th>Accession No.</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>12<td><td>ffyuyudf</td><td>61</td><td>Lost</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>12<td><td>ffyuyudf</td><td>62</td>Damaged</tr>  
    <tr><td>12<td><td>ffyuyudf</td><td>63</td>Damaged</tr>  
    <tr><td>13<td><td>abcdef</td><td>72</td>Lost</tr>  
    <tr><td>13<td><td>abcdef</td><td>73</td>Lost</tr>  
     ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to tweak the below lines

```
         $('#library_info_tbl tbody tr').each(function() {

                var statusarray = []; 
                var callno = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
                var accessionno = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
                var status = $(this).find("td:last-child").html();
                var callnotouse = "";
                 
                if(callno is similar) 
                {
                    var innerarray = {};
                        innerarray = {
                            status: status,
                            accessionno: accessionno
                       };      
                       statusarray.push(innerarray);
                       callnotouse = callno;
                }

                if(statusarray.length)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?action=savestatus',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {callno:callnotouse,statusarray:statusarray},
                      ...
                }
              continue; 
          });
```

for achieving statusarray and callnotouse in order to pass them in ajax call. Basically I want the code should work like first it should check similar call numbers in table for e.g in the above table.

It should first fetch on the basis of callno 12 and the innerarray or statusarray should contain data like

```
              status: Lost,
              accessionno: 61
                      
              status: Damaged,
              accessionno: 62
              
               status: Damaged,
               accessionno: 63

              callnotouse = 12
```

These data should get passed to ajax call (which will get saved in the database). After that, in the same of the loop of table it should take callno 13

```
          status: Lost,
          accessionno: 72

          status: Lost,
          accessionno: 73

          callnotouse = 13
```

Then it should get passed to ajax call and so. Basically I am not able to tweak the above code on the basis of similar callno.

Comment: is call number sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code

```
var libraryInfos = [];

$("#library_info_tbl tbody tr").each(function(){
  var tds = $("td", this);
  var callNo = tds.first().html();

  if(typeof libraryInfos[callNo] == 'undefined'){
    libraryInfos[callNo] = [];
  }

  libraryInfos[callNo].push({
    status: $(tds[4]).html(),
    accessionNo: parseInt($(tds[3]).html())
  });
});

$.each(libraryInfos, function(callNo, statusArr){
  if(statusArr){
    var reqData = { callno: callNo, statusarray: statusArr };

    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?action=savestatus',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: reqData
    });

    console.log(reqData);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/mamezit/5/edit?html,js,console,output